Hp Stream 11 g4 does not always boot
Laptop Hp Stream 11 Pro G4 EE, Win 10, Bios version F15, has been working just fine until suddenly, for no clear reason, I see these issues:

The laptop fails to start properly, when power button pressed:

Sometimes it boots normally
Sometimes it does nothing
Sometimes that caps lock led starts to flash, 1 times, 2 times or 3 times, whatever it feels like. I tends to hear a faint click coming from the laptop in this case sometimes the screen lights up, but then it stops again not booting into the OS


For the laptop to start the AC power MUST be connected, even with full battery

Once started, if we unplug the AC power, it drops dead instantly


I have replaced the battery but that made 0,0 difference, same issue is seen afterwards.
I have reset the bios/eufi, no avail. I have tried to upgrade bios to F18 and restarted but bios is still F15.
What can be the cause for this? How to fix it?

Sorry you're encountering this, seems frustrating. Unfortunately, we don't address troubleshooting questions on this StackExchange site; we only provide recommendations for new hardware. You may get more help on Super User.
